# Adapt OpenGL Code to Qt (espacially keyPressEvent)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a working program in OpenGL which shall now work under Qt. Some things are a bit different and I am struggling right now with the keypressevent-function. I have a global variable which should be changed by pressing a key (later by presing a button).

```
int modus = -1;

void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    switch (event->key())
    {
    case Qt::Key_F2 :
        modus = 1;
        updateGL();
        break; 
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This changed variable should be used in mousePressEvent()

```
void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if (modus == 1 && (e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
    {
        counter++;
        p_list[counter].x = mx - width1/2;                                  
        p_list[counter].y = my - height1/2;                 
        glPointSize(5);
        glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
        updateGL();
    }
}
```

Comment: OpenGL doesn't do input.  What GUI framework are you *really* converting from?

Comment: By the way, don't call `updateGL` directly, just call `update` as with any other `QWidget`.

Comment: He wants to bind OpenGL for 3D and Qt for input handling. Your idea with "modus" is compleatly wrong. Check for function that will check if in that moment there are any keys pressed. Also if you must, put int modus INSIDE your class that inherits QGLWidget.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you using Qt's [QGLWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qglwidget.html) class?

If you base your OpenGL class on QGLWidget, you can do something like this:

```
class QtGLStuff: public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
                    QtGLStuff();

    virtual void    keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* );
    virtual void    mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* );

private:
    int     mModus;
};
```

Then modus (which I renamed mModus to designate that it's a member datum) simply becomes data that the methods of your class share, rather than a global variable.